# Event Handlers passing sender thats not instanciated

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I am creating buttons on the fly and creating event handlers for them. When the code runs everything works fine as far as populating the menu on the fly successfully. When I click a button the event fires, but sender=Nothing and the Object is not set to instance exception comes up. Any Ideas? Must be missing something.

```
Imports DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim menu As New RibbonControl
        Dim aPage As New RibbonPage("Nicks Page")
        'groups'
        Dim aGroup1 As New RibbonPageGroup("1st Group")

        'ADD BUTTONS TO RIBBON GROUP HERE'
        Dim i As New DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem()
        i.Caption = "Nicks Button"
        AddHandler i.ItemClick, AddressOf y
        aGroup1.ItemLinks.Add(i)

        Dim i2 As New DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem()
        i2.Caption = "Nicks Other Button"
        AddHandler i2.ItemClick, AddressOf y
        aGroup1.ItemLinks.Add(i2)

        aPage.Groups.Add(aGroup1)
        menu.Pages.Add(aPage)
        Me.Controls.Add(menu)
    End Sub

    Private Sub y(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs)
        'EXCEPTION SENDER=NOTHING MSGBOX FAILS'
        MsgBox(CType(sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem).Caption)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *sender* is the BarManager.  Use e.Item instead.